# Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxMin, Version=4.97.4951.28478, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21ef50ce11b5d80f' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Get this error when I try to view my project in browser on localhost.

Verified that AjaxControlToolkit is setup in references in my project.

AjaxControlToolkit.dll is in the directory listed in the reference.

I re-installed AjaxControlToolkit to make sure that was not the issue.

The project I am working on is a project emailed to me by a colleague and is not something I created from the ground up. Not sure if that is the problem and the project is looking at an old reference?

On a related note, I have another test project in a separate solution and I added an AjaxControlToolkit control to test that (CalendarExtender) and it worked just fine.

Posting my code:

web config:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="TESTConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=TEST;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        <add name="TESTConnectionString2" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=TEST;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
      </connectionStrings>
      <system.web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">

          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>



          </assemblies>



       </compilation>

        <!--<pages>-->
          <!--<controls>

            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.97.4951.28478, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21ef50ce11b5d80f" />
            <add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="asp" />

            --><!--<add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.97.4951.28478, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21ef50ce11b5d80f"/>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.97.4951.28478, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21ef50ce11b5d80f"/>--><!--
          </controls>
        </pages>-->

      </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

master page:

```
 <%@ Master Language="C#" %>



    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />    
        <title></title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <%--<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>--%>

            <%--<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>--%>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Content2" runat="server" />
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" />

        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

top of the main .aspx page through the toolkitscriptmanager tag:

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MAIN.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin_Payments" %>


    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix ="asp" %>


    <asp:Content  ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">




        <style type="text/css">
            .auto-style1 {
                text-align: left;
                font-size: medium;
            }

            .auto-style2 {
                font-size: medium;
            }

            .auto-style3 {
                height: 577px;
            }
        </style>
    </asp:Content>

    <asp:Content contentplaceholderid="Content2" runat="Server">

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

..................

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341587/ajax-controls-toolkit-and-ajaxmin) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405508/using-ajaxmin-without-installing) possibly related question?

Comment: Check `assemblyBinding` in Web.Config. Does it exists?

Comment: esker - tried the first item posted by Teresa. Did not work. Did not understand the second.

Comment: Shahid - tried that but it had no effect.

Comment: @user2956257 If it exists remove it and then try it.

Comment: if you are using ToolkitScriptManager in master page template try removing it.

Comment: edited my original post to show my code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the answer. Apparently this was missing. Did as instructed and it worked. [Install AjaxMin package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxMin/)

Thanks to all who commented!

Answer (score 1):

Referencing the AjaxMin.dll did it for me.
It comes with the Ajax download: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/612416

Answer (score 1):

on your nuget console

```
Install-Package AjaxMin
```